# Matlab, gray level difference method

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have used the following function to calculate the probability density function for an image.
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25057-texture-feature-extraction-gldm/content/GLDM/GLDM.m
Can anyone tell me how I now go about extracting textural features such as contrast, mean, entropy etc. I have equations for these, I am just unsure of where to apply the equations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into "graycomatrix", which calculates the gray level co-occurrence matrix (GLCM), and "graycoprops", which calculates the contrast, correlation, energy, and homogeneity of an image based on the GLCM? These are some useful textural statistics. Requires the image-processing toolbox.